# Unable to group the subtracted dates in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Requirement: To subtract the two dates (date1 and date2) and find average of them

Following is the query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $match: {
         created_date: {
                $gte: ISODate("2020-02-24T00:00:00.000Z"),
                $lt: ISODate("2020-08-25T00:00:00.000Z")
            }
        }
    },{
        $project: {
            dateDifference: {$divide : [ { $subtract: ["$date1" ,"$date2"] }, 1000 * 60 * 60] }
        }
    }
    ,{
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            
            dateDifference1: { 
                $avg: "$dateDifference"
            }
        }
    }
   
]);
```

The Error while grouping for average:

```
{
    "message" : "cant $subtract adate from a string",
    "ok" : 0,
    "code" : 16556,
    "codeName" : "Location16556",
    "name" : "MongoError"
}
```

Sample Input Document:

```
/* 1 createdAt:2/24/2020, 5:39:08 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e53142405cf030001c6a8bd"),
    "date2" : ISODate("2020-02-24T05:36:50.000+05:30"),
    "date1" : ISODate("2020-02-24T18:24:28.698+05:30"),
    "dateDifference" : 12.794082777777778
}
```

Comment: Can we see a sample document?  Apparently `date1` or `date2` contains a string for at least one matching document.

Comment: I have updated the question with the sample document @joe

Comment: That document doesn't contain either `date1` or `date2`, where do those come from?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake i have updated the document

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that at least one document in the collection has a string for one of the date fields instead of an ISODate.

You can identify those with find:

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {date2: {$type: "string"}},
    {date1: {$type: "string"}}
  ]
})
```

Or you could add another project stage before the existing one to ensure both fields are dates:

```
{$proejct: {
      date1: {
        $cond: {
          if: {$eq: [{$type: "$date1"},"string"]},
          then: {$dateFromString: {dateString: "$date1"}},
          else: "$date1"
        }
      },
      date2: {
        $cond: {
          if: {$eq: [{$type: "$date2"},"string"]},
          then: {$dateFromString: {dateString: "$date2"}},
          else: "$date2"
        }
      }
 }}
```

Note that this will also throw an error if there are date1 or date2 fields containing strings that are not valid dates.